# Rails form drop down select data from database pulled from a different table

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have three models that are connected like the following

```
Users
has_many :training_resources, through: :user_training_resources
has_many :user_training_resources, dependent: :destroy

TrainingResources
has_many :user_training_resource, dependent: :destroy
has_many :users, through: :user_training_resource

UserTrainingResources
belongs_to :user
belongs_to :training_resource
```

I'm trying to build out a form on my TrainingResource show page to allow the user to change the status of a UserTrainingResource and it's failed pretty miserably.

This is the latest attempt:

```
        <% @training_resource.spud_users.each do |training| %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= training.full_name %></td>
        <% utr = training.user_training_resources.where(training_resource: @training_resource).first %>
        <td>
             <%= tb_form_for [:admin, @training_resource], :remote => true, :data => {:errors => :inline, :success => admin_training_resources_path} do |f| %>
               <%= f.collection_select :user_training_resource_ids, @training_resource, :id, :name %>
               <%= f.tb_save_buttons('', admin_training_resources_path) %>
             <% end %>
        </td>
        <td class="table-actions">
          <%= link_to 'Delete', admin_user_training_resource_path(training), :method => :delete, :data => {:confirm => 'Are you sure you want to delete this?'}, :class => 'btn btn-danger btn-sm'  %>
        </td>
      </tr>
    <% end %>
```

The delete works fine but the select at the moment errors out with: undefined method 'map'.

I've also tried:

```
<%= f.select(:user_training_resource_ids, UserTrainingResource.pluck(:status, :id))%>
```

No error on the page but the options displayed appear to display the current status for ALL UserTrainingResource. Plus it's not actually saving a change.

I've tried:

```
<%= f.select(:user_training_resource_ids, options_for_select(['pending', 'confirmed', 'rejected'], selected: utr.status))%>
```

This actually does present the options because I'm being explicit and it's actually showing the current status. However it's not saving when a selection is made.

Is this just a simple issue of a wrong route? Is there a better way to select data from a different table in a rails drop down?

Edit:

Here's the UserTrainingResources Controller. It's pointing to the TrainingResources Controller's Admin:

```
class Admin::UserTrainingResourcesController < Admin::ApplicationController
 belongs_to_app :training_resources
 add_breadcrumb 'Training Resources', :admin_training_resources_path
 before_action :load_training_resource, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
 respond_to :html, :json

 def new
   @user_training_resource = UserTrainingResource.new
   respond_with @user_training_resource
 end 

 def edit
  respond_with @user_training_resource
 end

 def show 
  respond_with @user_training_resource
end

def update 
  flash[:notice] = 'UserTrainingResource updated successfully' if @user_training_resource.update(user_training_resource_params)
  respond_with @user_training_resource, location: admin_training_resources_path
end

def destroy
  flash[:notice] = 'UserTrainingResource deleted successfully' if @user_training_resource.destroy
  respond_with @user_training_resource, location: admin_training_resources_path
end

private

def load_training_resource
  @user_training_resource = UserTrainingResource.find_by!(id: params[:id])
end

def user_training_resource_params
  params.require(:user_training_resources).permit(
  :training_resources_id, :status).merge(user_id: current_user_id)
end

end
```

Another edit: Routes

I feel like this is an issue with saving to the correct place so I've included below the routes for user_training_resources:

```
get '/user_training_resources' => 'user_training_resources#index'
delete '/user_training_resources/:id' => 'user_training_resources#destroy', as: :destroy_utr
put '/user_training_resources/:id' => 'user_training_resources#update', as: :update_utr
```

Comment: Post your respective controller code

Comment: added the controller for UserTrainingResource as it connects to TrainingResource.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is actually the `form_for` being passed to the wrong url. Changed it to reflect a new path url: `admin_update_utr_path(utr)`

Answer (score 0):

It may well be the route - the route for the form using the POST or PATCH (not sure which) method while your route is expecting a PUT method.

To confirm, check your console to see if the route is resolving to the correct controller action.  If not, you can either change the routes to be like:

```
post '/user_training_resources/:id' => 'user_training_resources#update', as: :update_utr
```

or 
    patch '/user_training_resources/:id' => 'user_training_resources#update', as: :update_utr

Comment: Actually the console was expecting patch instead of put. Changed the route as well.

Answer (score -1):

I think you need to set "multiple" because @training_resource can has many "user_training_resource_ids"

try this :

```
<%= f.collection_select :user_training_resource_ids, current_user.user_training_resources, 
                        :id, :name, 
                        {:prompt => "Please select training resources"}, 
                        {:multiple => true} %>
```

source : https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html#method-i-collection_select

Comment: Multiple would allow the user to select multiple different statuses on a singular status. Think of it as Mary is looking at a bunch of training requests for all the employees. Each row is a different employee and/or it's a different request from each employee. She needs to be able to change someones request from pending to confirmed or confirmed to rejected, etc. This unfortunately doesn't put in the current status just displays one and doesn't save.